# Issue with disabling Jenkin's job from another Jenkin's job using Groovy command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

[image: Screen shot of jenkin's configuration]

For some reason the added command to disable another Jenkin's job does not work.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: add this println "Disabled: ${Jenkins.Instance.getItem("Jobq").isDisabled()}" and see it if actually got disabled  also print the job name and see if that is the job you are triyng to disable

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response was travelling and i did check if it disabled but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is old question but if someone finds it here is an answer. You should use **System Groovy script** section instead that one and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Risha 's answer, refer to the notes on the [groovy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/).

**Groovy Script vs System Groovy Script**

The plain "Groovy Script" is run in a forked JVM, on the agent where the build is run. It's the basically the same as running the "groovy" command and pass in the script.

The system Groovy script on the other hand runs inside the Jenkins master's JVM. Thus it will have access to all the internal objects of Jenkins, so you can use this to alter the state of Jenkins. It is similar to the [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Consoleb functionality.

**Security**

System groovy jobs has access to whole Jenkins, therefore only users with admin rights can add system Groovy build step and configure the system Groovy script.

---

Your normal (standalone) Groovy step will run on a node using the chosen account and will not have access to the Jenkins data, whereas System Groovy runs on the master w/full access to data as noted.

Using @Rohit 's command to print status would help you.
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder_name/job_name').isDisabled()}"

Better is to test before if not disabled, then disable and check if result is successful. PS: do you also want to test/kill a running instance of other job is running (job.isBuilding())?

Answer (score 0):

For me the above given solutions were not working, but I tried in the *System Groovy script*

following way and it works fine :)

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder/Sub_Folder/jobName').setDisabled(false)
```